# Is there a function in pandas that look for "gaps" of some data in dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with looking for gaps in my pandas dataframe.

So I have this data in my df:

| date | name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | FEAT_1 | 0.64 |
| 2020-01-01 | FEAT_2 | 0.17 |
| 2020-01-01 | FEAT_3 | 0.09 |
| 2020-01-01 | FEAT_4 | 0.07 |
| 2020-01-01 | FEAT_5 | 0.03 |
| 2020-01-02 | FEAT_1 | 0.90 |
| 2020-01-02 | FEAT_2 | 0.30 |
| 2020-01-02 | FEAT_3 | 0.20 |
| 2020-01-02 | FEAT_4 | 0.10 |
| 2020-01-02 | FEAT_6 | 0.02 |

And what I want to do is to fill rows for dates that miss some `FEAT_N`. So, for example `2020-01-01` has `feat1,2,3,4,5` but doesn't have `feat_6` and I would like to put there new row with same `date`, `feat_6` as name and `score = 0`. FEAT_N are `.unique()` values of column `feature_name`

I don't know how to deal with this problem. My main problem is that I don't know how to find if certain date in date column has FEAT_N value.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with by using a `MultiIndex` in pandas.

1. Set the index to a `MultiIndex` of "date" and "name"
2. Create a new `MultiIndex` that is the cartesian product of the current `MultiIndex`
3. `reindex` your data filling with 0

```py
df = df.set_index(["date", "name"])
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels)
new_df = df.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
print(new_df)
                   score
date       name
2020-01-01 FEAT_1   0.64
           FEAT_2   0.17
           FEAT_3   0.09
           FEAT_4   0.07
           FEAT_5   0.03
           FEAT_6   0.00
2020-01-02 FEAT_1   0.90
           FEAT_2   0.30
           FEAT_3   0.20
           FEAT_4   0.10
           FEAT_5   0.00
           FEAT_6   0.02
```

---

Below is the exact same approach, but intended to please the method chaining addicts:

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index(["date", "name"])
    .pipe(lambda df:
        df.reindex(
            pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels), 
            fill_value=0
        )
    )
)

print(new_df)
                   score
date       name
2020-01-01 FEAT_1   0.64
           FEAT_2   0.17
           FEAT_3   0.09
           FEAT_4   0.07
           FEAT_5   0.03
           FEAT_6   0.00
2020-01-02 FEAT_1   0.90
           FEAT_2   0.30
           FEAT_3   0.20
           FEAT_4   0.10
           FEAT_5   0.00
           FEAT_6   0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to create a "grid" dataframe containing all the column pairs you want, outer-join it with your data frame, then set the missing values to your default (0):

```
import pandas as pd

keys1 = df['date'].unique()
keys2 = df['name'].unique()
# get all possible date-name pairs
default = [[k1, k2] for k1 in keys1 for k2 in keys2]
df_default = pd.DataFrame(default, columns=['date', 'name'])

# outer merge
df_complete = pd.merge(df, df_default, on=['date', 'name'], how='outer')
# fill in the missing value with a reasonable default
df_complete['score'] = df_complete['score'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If these values are required, I'd suggest maybe turning them into columns, e.g. `date | FEAT_1_score | FEAT_2_score`, etc.

Then, you can fill those columns with either the scores in your current data, or the 0 value.

Here's a rough approximation of the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-01'], 'name':["FEAT_1", "FEAT_3"], 'score':['0.5', '0.6']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def index_value_or_zero(x, df, feat):
    index_value = df.loc[(df["date"] == x.date) & (df["name"] == feat)]["score"]
    if len(index_value) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return index_value

df["FEAT_1_score"] = df.apply(lambda x: index_value_or_zero(x, df, "FEAT_1"), axis=1)
df["FEAT_2_score"] = df.apply(lambda x: index_value_or_zero(x, df, "FEAT_2"), axis=1)
df["FEAT_3_score"] = df.apply(lambda x: index_value_or_zero(x, df, "FEAT_3"), axis=1)

df = df.drop("score", axis=1).drop("name", axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates()

df
```

returns:

```
    date        FEAT_1_score    FEAT_2_score    FEAT_3_score
0   2020-01-01  0.5             0               0.6
```